# Multimeter Voltage doesn't match ECU Voltage

Tags: alternator, electronic-control-module

I was messing around with electrical loads on my 98 Mazda 626 GF 2L today and noticed that the voltage I was reading at the battery with my multimeter, didn't match the voltage the ECU was report via my scan tool.  I'm sure the multimeter was correct.

I took measurements at idle, with no load and with all the electrical loads turned on ( high beams, radio, blower, defroster ) and the difference between the multimeter and ECU readers varied between 0.25 to 0.5 volts.

What might cause this discrepancy?  Might I have a voltage drop problem somewhere on the path to the ECU?

Comment: What were the readings?  Did you try measuring the voltage at the pin on the connector for the ECU?

Comment: @rpmerf I took a variety of readings.  Typically the difference was between 1/4 to 1/2 a volt.

Comment: .5v is more than you would like to see, Generally .25v is acceptable.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes I tend to start with grounds since they are easiest.  Did you always use the battery for a ground, or did you ground to random location on the body?  If you always use the battery, only the positive side is a variable.  After that, follow it to the fuse box, ignition switch, ECU and see where it drops off at.

Comment: It would also help to write something about the status of the car while measuring. Was it running? Any heavy load like blower, lights on?

Comment: @sweber see my edit.

Comment: The type of multimeter could cause a lower reading depending on it's volt-ohm sensitivity rating. For example, an Analog meter reads in the range of K-ohms/volt whereas a digital meter reads in the range of M-ohm/volt.

Comment: @resident_heretic It's the digital multimeter which is giving a higher reading than the ECU.

Comment: @RSB: Your scan tool has lower ohm-volt sensitivity than the DVM , The DVM would tend to read a little  higher due to less circuit loading.

Comment: Earth points, corrosion in connectors and wire lengths could all account for differences.  As could gauge calibration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that part of the reason the voltage didn't match is because I was using a very cheap multimeter.  I got a good Uni-T meter and with the engine off my cheap meter was showing 12.92v and the Uni-T was showing 12.74v.  This was after I'd been driving around a bit, so I'm sure there was still a bit of surface charge.  I checked again later and can pretty much chalk this up to an inaccurate reading by a cheap multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented in your *very* similar question about alternator voltage, where you are measuring voltage and where the ECU does are two different locations.  Voltage drop test all the main battery cables and wiring.